# How to get the link of prev/next wp_link_pages and redirect it with js?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to have pagination with navigation arrow keys, I already create code to redirect it, but I don't know how to get the link of prev/next page wp_link_pages.
Any help?

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return;
  }

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      location.href = '<?php echo $previous_page_url; ?>';
    break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        location.href = '<?php echo $next_page_url;?>';
    break;
    default:
      return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}, true);
</script>
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages

Comment: I already read them all and not found any information that can be used for this issue.

Comment: Well you could either use this function directly to output the links somewhere on the page, hide them if you don’t want the user to see them (might be a bad idea though; not everyone might use keyboard navigation or even _have_ a keyboard on the device they are using to view your site), and simply have your JS read the URLs from there (or trigger a click on those links.)

Comment: If that doesn’t suit your needs, if you check the source code of that function, you will notice that it uses a helper function `_wp_link_page` that only gets the index of the page you want to navigate to passed as parameter, so if you know where you are currently “at”, you could use that to generate individual links (or take it as a starting point if you don’t want the actual HTML code for the link, but the URL only.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice and information. I will check the source code, and search other function may connected with wp_link_pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

```
get_permalink() . ( $page - 1 )
get_permalink() . ( $page + 1 )
```

You can use them in your like this:

```
switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      location.href = '<?php $page > 1 ? get_permalink() . ( $page - 1 ) : get_permalink(); ?>';
    break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      location.href = '<?php echo $page < $numpages ? get_permalink() . ( $page + 1 ) : get_permalink(); ?>';
    break;
    default:
      return;
}
```

Comment: No, not that. I split the post into several page with <!--nextpage-->

Comment: Thank you! this is the answer that fits perfectly with this issue.